# AS3 using array to add EventListener to existing Button

Tags: actionscript-3, arrays, button, addeventlistener, cs4

I'm trying to use an array to add a click listener to an existing Button.
Black,Blue...etc are the button Names.
the location of the nested button would be:
this.mc1.mc2.contents.m3.black.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doThisFunction);

```
 var myArray:Array = new Array ("black","blue","green","orange");
 for(var k:int =1; k<myArray.length; k++){ 
   var kmc:MovieClip = (myArray[k] as MovieClip);
         this.mc1.mc2.contents.m3.kmc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doThisFunction);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First `kmc` is a String:

```
var kmc:String = myArray[k];
```

Then the last line should be:

```
this.mc1.mc2.contents.m3[kmc].addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doThisFunction);
```

Comment: That certainly helps a lot! It's creating the first 2 listeners (I changed the myArray[k] to myArray[k-1]) and not the last 2.  Did I miss something on the 'for' statement?

Comment: Never mind, I had a copy of the MC over the clip I was trying to click...  
Thanks for your help!